# Get last non NaN value after groupby and aggregation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this for example:

```
       col1         col2
0       A            3
1       B            4
2       A            NaN
3       B            5  
4       A            5
5       A            NaN
6       B            NaN
.
.
.
47      B            8
48      A            9
49      B            NaN         
50      A            NaN
```

when i try `df.groupby(['col1'], sort=False).agg({'col2':'last'}).reset_index()` it gives me this output

```
      col1      col2
0     A          NaN
1     B          NaN
```

I want to get the last non NaN value after groupby and agg. The desirable output is like below

```
      col1      col2
0     A          9
1     B          8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your solution working well, if `NaN` are missing values.

Here is alternative:

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['col2']).drop_duplicates('col1', keep='last')
```

If NaNs are strings first convert them to missing values:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].replace('NaN', np.nan)
df.groupby(['col1'], sort=False).agg({'col2':'last'}).reset_index()
```